# Inserting annotations into Retrofit request for Jackson

Tags: java, android, jackson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2.1 and Jackson in an Android app to make a post call to a service which is using Jackson to deserialize.  The service is expecting the incoming json to look like:

```
{"@class":"com.servicepackagepath$OurClassName","prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2"}
```

however the json that's getting generated and being sent to the service is:

```
{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2"}
```

resulting in a 500.  The retrofit signature looks like:

```
@POST("apiName")
Call<String> apiName(@Body OurClassName ourClassName);
```

OurClassName class on the client side is a different class than the one on the service.  Exactly the same signature, but it's local.

How can I get that @class annotation to get inserted into the outgoing json?

Comment: I got it working by creating a custom json object, inserting the annotation, then appending a gson deserialized to json representation of my object, and passing the jsonobject to the service.  It works, but it's a total hack and shouldn't be how retrofit is used so I'm not gonna create an answer for it.  What's the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.  You need to add to your Retrofit Builder:

```
.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(
    new ObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
))
```

and then on top of your class declaration do:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
```